# Sagemaker: Problem with elastic inference when deploying

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, deployment, amazon-sagemaker

When executing the deploy code to **sagemaker** using **sagemaker-python-sdk** I get error as :

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint tensorflow-inference-eia-XXXX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XXX: 
Failed. Reason: The image '763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference-eia:1.14 
-gpu' does not exist..
```

The code that I am using to deploy is as:

```
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                         instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge', accelerator_type='ml.eia1.medium')
```

If I remove the `accelerator_type` parameter then the endpoint gets deployed with no errors. Any idea on why this happens? Sagemaker seems to be referring to the image that doesn't exist. How do I fix this?

Also, I made sure that the version is supported from here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk#tensorflow-sagemaker-estimators'. I am on TensorFlow: 1.14.

> **Edit:**
>   Turns out, this works:

```
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                         instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', accelerator_type='ml.eia1.medium')
```

So, I am guessing that elastic inference is not available for GPU instances?

> Note: None of the instances that I deploy my endpoint to is using GPU. (Please suggest some ideas if you are familiar or have made it work.)

Comment: This is not a new issue. I don't know the exact problem with your particular setup because there are several moving parts that I don't see but this might help you https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/912

Comment: Hi @MatusDubrava, Thanks for the reply. I already checked the link that you provided. The thing is that I can deploy the endpoint successfully if I do not mention the `accelerator_type` parameter. The link focuses on the `instance_type` parameter. I am willing to try other things, any suggestions?

Comment: If you are running on a GPU instance, why would you want to add an elastic interface? The GPU is already providing the acceleration that you need.

Comment: @Guy, hey, thanks for the reply. After I deploy the model to the endpoint I found that the inference is not taking GPU. So, I wanted to test this with elastic inference. Any idea on this?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya, from your question edit it looks that when you attached the elastic interface to a CPU based machine (M4, for example), you managed to get it to work. Right?

Comment: @Guy, oh really sorry for the confusion here. I still am not able to get GPU power in any instance + elastic inference combination. I have tried 8 - 9 combinations up till now.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Inference Accelerator (EIA) are designed to be attached to CPU endpoints.